# Redis Predis and PHP

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redis, predis

I'm working on using Redis with Flash AS3.

- I've installed Redis and Predis on a Win7 environment (MSTech for the Redis) and have a RedisAs3 client.
- My localHost is `192.168.1.2` and I've configured Redis to listen on `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.1.2`.

I only want the AS3 client to subscribe and will eventually get PHP to publish.

Testing in the Flash IDE and using the redisCLI to publish, everything works fine. However, trying my app on my localhost, I get nothing, not connection no error and I can't work out what's going wrong.

Totally new at Redis, Predis but would appreciate some help/guidance.

Comment: Your localhost server is enabled/running? Can you ping `192.168.1.2`?

Comment: Absolutely. I can access the flash app not problem on 192.168.1.2. In the IDE var redis = new redis(192.168.1.2, 3967) works fine and when I use clientlist on the redis cli its listed there too. In the browser though - nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

What was missing here was a [**socket policy file**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html). It's entirely separate from the standard crossdomain policy file and so I needed to serve my app with a socket policy file.

I managered to get a policyFile server running as a windows service from here: 
 **https://socketpolicyfile.codeplex.com/**

Now works like a charm.. Hope this helps others